# Beyond reproach - alternative expressions

Tags: expressions, idioms, synonyms

What are some alternative, diplomatic ways to say "beyond reproach", "above question", "of the path that is ethically spotless/sound and cannot be challenged".

I was thinking, "unquestionable", but that doesn't sound quite right.

Context - a diplomatic email:

> It’s worth noting that we only sell genuine software via the official
>   and sanctioned channels.  You might be able to get black market
>   software elsewhere on the cheap, but as an official government
>   organisation of the highest order, I would imagine it in your interest
>   to always take the path that is above question.

Another variation:

> It’s worth noting that we only sell genuine software via the official
>   and sanctioned channels.  You might be able to get black market
>   software elsewhere on the cheap, but as an official government
>   organisation of the highest order, I would imagine it in your interest
>   to always take the path that is beyond reproach and safeguards your
>   ethical reputation in a public office.

Comment: I’m afraid this is rather too open-ended to be a good fit for the StackExchange model – the ‘correct’ answer will always be a matter of opinion and preference. I might write something along the lines of, “I would imagine it in your interest to always choose the morally and ethically irreproachable path”, but others may have completely different suggestions and opinions.

Comment: Indeed, friend, I do not seek a single correct answer; just enough options that I might find what feels right amongst them.  :)

Answer (score -1):

Janus mentions "irreproachable" as a synonym for "beyond reproach", and with that as a clue, you could go to [thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/irreproachable) or [over 60 other synonym websites](https://www.google.com/search?q=synonym%20irreproachable) for good words with similar meanings. Also, if ever referring to an actual person, please consider less hyperbolic compliments like "honest", "reliable", "of good character", which oddly enough tend to be taken more seriously precisely because they are more measured.